# What is a split or branch or lines in a Water and Sewage Organization called?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

What is a split or branch or lines in a Water and Sewage Organization called?
I mean the split or lines that are sold to the customers, each customer (home) has one of these lines or splits.
Currently we call this "water splits" but i am not sure if its correct because it doesn't sound very good.

Comment: From [DIY in an hour](http://diyinahour.com/diy/plumbing-the-main-drain-water-supply-system/), acceptable terms are 'water service line' (aka 'external supply pipe' from another source), and for sewerage 'property service connection' / 'sanitary sewer lateral' /'house lateral' / 'private drain' (other sources). How prosaic. There may be others; I suspect terminology isn't standard.

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. Who is "we" and where are you? Also, in English, we don't say water and sewage organization. We say water and sewage pipes or layout of water and sewage pipes. Please improve  your question. Thank you. utility hook-ups are also a "thing".

Comment: A water split sounds like a _really_ boring dessert.

Comment: @Lambie When i say we, i mean me and my company, we are kinda an Arabic company and we are creating a business document of the water organization in our country,by water organization i mean the organization and the company which handles the water supply and sewage system of the whole country, the document is in English and we simply can't find the appropriate equivalent term for some of these technical words, one of them is "ensheab" which we translated to "water split" :d.

Comment: Please try use a capital letter for the pronoun I. We don't say "water organization". You mean: water supply company for the water distribution system in your country. When two pipes branch off, that can be a branching system. Look at thisL https://slideplayer.com/slide/6622518/ [Arab country, Arabic language]

Answer (score -2):

I mean the split or lines **that are sold to the customers**, each customer (home) has one of these lines or splits.

---

I can only speak about the UK but it would be a **connection**. The arrangement  **is different to your explanation**. The reason being that the branch to a property belongs to the Water or Sewage company up to the connection point. This is easily identified in water and gas supplies it will be where your meter is. The meter belongs to the supplier then your pipes connect after the meter.

Normally referred to in everyday speech as "**The Mains connection**" or **"connection to The Mains**" albeit it **Gas or water**.

As Edwin has quoted in comments  **'property service connection'** is the correct term for sewage, this would also be correct for gas and water

[Seven Trent Water](https://www.stwater.co.uk/content/dam/stw/stw_buildinganddeveloping/new-connections/new-connections-charging-arrangement-2019-2020.pdf)